# SQLite Join Causing Duplicate Data After First Correct Record

Tags: sqlite

I am having an issue where after the first record in a Select statement the data in a certain column is being duplicated within the Select statement. I will provide the statement in which I am working with:

```
SELECT Call.CallID AS [Call #],
   (Members.FirstName || ' ' || Members.LastName) AS OIC,
   Alarm.AlarmID,
   Alarm.AlarmDesc AS Alarm,
 --Group_Concat(m2.FirstName || ' ' || m2.LastName) AS [Line Officers],
   Group_Concat(m1.FirstName || ' ' || m1.LastName) AS Members
FROM Call
   LEFT JOIN
   Members ON Call.OIC = Members.MemberID
   LEFT JOIN
   Alarm ON Call.AlarmID = Alarm.AlarmID
   LEFT JOIN
   CallToMembers ON Call.CallID = CallToMembers.CallID
 --LEFT JOIN 
 --CallToLineOfficers on Call.CallID = CallToLineOfficers.CallID
   LEFT JOIN
   Members AS m1 ON CallToMembers.MemberID = m1.MemberID
 --LEFT JOIN
 --Members as m2 on CallToLineOfficers.MemberID = m2.MemberID
GROUP BY Call.CallID;
```

Ok, so this statement returns everything that I need and is working perfectly. However, whenever I uncomment the lines that are commented out so that I can obtain "Line Officers" from the Bridge Table "CallToLineOfficers", data begins to duplicate from within the columns like so:

**Incorrect Complete Select Statement**
- Nothing commented out.
[image: Incorrect Complete Select Statement]
**Correct Line Officers**
- If I comment Joins for CallToMembers.
[image: Correct Line Officers]
**Correct Members**
- If I comment Joins for CallToLineOfficers.
[image: Correct Members]

As you can see that once I introduce both "Members" and "Line Officers", things go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you join the calls with the line officers, you get an intermediate result like this:

```
Call #  Line Officers
------  -------------
54      Bob Clark
54      Rob Catalano
```

When you then join with the members, the database matches the call number again, so for *each* row in the intermediate result, you get *all* combinations with the members:

```
Call #  Line Officers  Members
------  -------------  -----------
54      Bob Clark      Matt Butler
54      Rob Catalano   Matt Butler
54      Bob Clark      Tom Cramer
54      Rob Catalano   Tom Cramer
...
```

So you cannot use joins when you have multiple independent tables with 1:N relationships.

You don't actually want to have multiple line officer/member rows in the result anyway, so you can just use a subquery to aggregate those values:

```
SELECT CallID,
       (SELECT group_concat(FirstName || ' ' || LastName)
        FROM CallToLineOfficers
        JOIN Members USING (MemberID)
        WHERE CallID = Call.CallID
       ) AS "Line Officers",
       (SELECT group_concat(FirstName || ' ' || LastName)
        FROM CallToMembers
        JOIN Members USING (MemberID)
        WHERE CallID = Call.CallID
       ) AS Members
FROM Call;
```

Comment: Wow, great! So question. Any time that I need to select from a potential 1:N table, I should use a subquery to do a separate select for such column in order to avoid getting duplicate data?

Comment: That depends on what kind of result you want to get out of it.